# how do i plot data from MongoDB on OSM?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, node.js, mongodb

The data stored in my Database "video" of "shows" collection in mongodb is as [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQ7tF.jpg). It has 3 feilds as dose_rate, x, y.

My code for "app.js" is as follows :

```
var express=require('express');
var MongoClient=require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var engines=require('consolidate');
var assert=require('assert');
var app=express();

app.engine('html',engines.nunjucks);
app.set('view engine','html');
app.set('views',__dirname+ '/views');

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/video',function(err,db){
assert.equal(null,err);
console.log("successfully connect to the MongoDB server");
app.get('/',function(req,res){
    db.collection('shows').find({}).toArray(function(err,docs){
        res.render('shows',{'shows':docs});
        });
      });
    });
 });

app.listen(4596,function(req,res){
console.log("connect to the port 4596");
});
```

the below code is for "shows.html" :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Plotting points</title>
</head>
<body>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        {%for show in shows%}
            <li>{{show.dose_rate}}</li>
            <li> {{show.x}}</li>
            <li>{{show.y}}</li>
        {%endfor%}
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

on running the code of "app.js" and on opening "shows.html" from browser on localhost, the output is that all points (i.e dose_rate, x, y) of my "shows" collection in "video" database is displayed  on HTML page as [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6LZTp.png).

Now i have code for plotting single point (77.5,18.1025)on OSM *INDEPENDENTLY* as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html> 
<head>
    <title>OpenLayers Simplest Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="Map" style="height:600px"></div>
    <script src="/home/padmesh/mean/osm sample/OpenLayers.js"></script>
    <script>
        var lat            = 77.5;
        var lon            = 18.1025;
        var zoom           = 10;

        var fromProjection = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"); //Transform from WGS 1984
        var toProjection   = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"); //to Spherical Mercator Projection
        var position       = new OpenLayers.LonLat(lat,lon).transform( fromProjection, toProjection);

        map = new OpenLayers.Map("Map");
        var mapnik         = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM();
        map.addLayer(mapnik);

        var markers = new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers( "Markers" );
        map.addLayer(markers);
        markers.addMarker(new OpenLayers.Marker(position));

        map.setCenter(position, zoom);

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**I want to plot all my points stored in my collection "shows" as "x" and "y" from that db on OSM map, one by one, at once. I tried finding all reference to this problem but failed to find one. Please help me in doing so as i am new to OSM and nodejs or post any reference which i can read or tag someone who can help. THANK YOU IN ADVANCE**